# How I completely remove all ros from my system?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

The ros path and different versions of ros couses problem in my system.
I want to completely uninstall ros from my system. I want to completely remove all things related to ros from my system. How can I done this?

Then wan't to install a fresh ROS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57213/how-i-completely-remove-all-ros-from-my-system?/) by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on ROS Answers with karma: 313 on 2013-03-05

Post score: 18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're running Ubuntu, and installed ROS with apt-get, the first step would be

```
sudo apt-get remove ros-*
```

If you've created a workspace, you'll have to also remove that... and if you added the setup scripts to your .bashrc, you'd have to remove them too.

If you've installed from source then it will be more complicated.

---

Originally posted by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) with karma: 837 on 2013-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 39

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [newbieros](https://answers.ros.org/users/23682/newbieros/) on 2015-10-07**:
hello,
Actually I had both indigo and jade installed in my system. I tried to remove jade by **sudo apt-get remove ros-jade**  but it shows unable to locate package ros-jade. I want to remove only jade

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-01-12**:
Hai, I am completely new to ros and linux. Can you pls tell me how to remove added scripts from .bashrc. Also I believe that removing workspace simply means removing the folder. Kindly help

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-03-30**:
@newbieros did you try `$ sudo apt-get remove ros-jade-*` ? You have to add the asterisk in there.

**Comment by [pacifickid9](https://answers.ros.org/users/32335/pacifickid9/) on 2017-10-20**:
@Jon what if you did install it from a source? what do you have to do to remove it?

**Comment by [Kaustubh Patil](https://answers.ros.org/users/51893/kaustubh-patil/) on 2020-02-18**:
i removed ROS using the command and deleted catkin_ws manually
but still when i open my terminal i see this.........

bash: /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/kaustubh/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory

kaustubh@ubuntu:~$

Please help me get rid of this

**Comment by [Jaapy](https://answers.ros.org/users/51906/jaapy/) on 2020-02-19**:
@Kaustubh Patil - if you are on Ubuntu you have to remove the line from .bashrc:
Edit the file ./bashrc:
sudo nano ~/.bashrc

The remove the line that looks something like this: : source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash

**Comment by [33thou](https://answers.ros.org/users/55949/33thou/) on 2020-10-05**:
Note that this syntax does not work between `apt` versions 1.9.9 and 2.0.2: https://askubuntu.com/a/1218821

Instead, use `sudo apt uninstall '?name(ros-*)'`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
First thing to do is: sudo apt-get remove ros-*
as Jon Stephan said before.
Then, you should check your ~/.bashrc (as noted before).
Check for your /opt/ directory, where a ROS folder may still exist.

Reboot.
You might want to verify that ROS is completely removed by echoing ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or other variables.

---

Originally posted by [aimc](https://answers.ros.org/users/3966/aimc/) with karma: 216 on 2013-03-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MKI](https://answers.ros.org/users/8136/mki/) on 2014-06-19**:
Hi, I would like add a point here. I tried the above remove command. All the files were removed except for a folder in /etc/ros/rosdep/. This folder contains the sources list. I believe this too should be removed. Please correct me if I am wrong. thank you.

**Comment by [kaygudo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25082/kaygudo/) on 2015-12-18**:
MKI do u knw how to remove it?

**Comment by [Nebula](https://answers.ros.org/users/33043/nebula/) on 2018-03-15**:
You need to do with sudo rm command.

```
sudo rm 20-default.list
```

**Comment by [spkadam](https://answers.ros.org/users/44549/spkadam/) on 2020-04-13**:\

> sudo rm
> /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use

> sudo apt-get purge ros-*

It will also remove configuration files. And then

> sudo apt-get autoremove

To remove dependencies

---

Originally posted by [tonyParker](https://answers.ros.org/users/15131/tonyparker/) with karma: 377 on 2014-09-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 22

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/26971/aidos/) on 2016-05-24**:
Hi! Could you tell me if I should manually delete catkin_ws folder?

**Comment by [aidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/26971/aidos/) on 2016-05-24**:
There is also one interesting thing occurred while the purging process: it has deleted "Krusader" file manager from my system. I am new to Ubuntu, so I don't know why this purge command has also done this.

**Comment by [nh2](https://answers.ros.org/users/27692/nh2/) on 2016-08-06**:
The command should be `sudo apt-get purge '^ros-*'`, to match really only things that **start** with `ros-`, otherwise it will uninstall other packages that contain the string `ros`, like things with `microsoft` in the name (this is probably also the answer to your problem, @aidos).

**Comment by [ixtiyoruz](https://answers.ros.org/users/51823/ixtiyoruz/) on 2020-08-12**:
aidos, you should not delete catkin_ws folder it is yours. If you want to delete only catkin_ws you can delete it separately, and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I know its coming in quite late, but if anyone else is looking for the solution:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove ros-<distro_name>-desktop-full
```

replace <distro_name> with the distro you are currently using, in my case, melodic:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove ros-melodic-desktop-full
```

---

Originally posted by [gokulp01](https://answers.ros.org/users/54794/gokulp01/) with karma: 31 on 2021-08-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3